# Ubuntu willy werwolf isnt working on my computer dell xps 8700

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell

My computer is dell xps 8700 , nvidia 745 gtx, intel core 7. I tried to install ubuntu willy werewolf on my desktop but it didn't work. The graphic look horrible. words aren't showing correctly. some letters are missing. I tried  one  month ago ubuntu 15.04  This version worked correctly. and it's 14.04 work correctly too.Please help.
Your sincerely Agnieszka

Comment: Try booting into recovery mode and switching back to open-source drivers (if you are using proprietary ones)

Comment: The problem is starrting when I try to install ubuntu 15.10 At the beggining.

Comment: As i understand you are trying to do a clean install? with a pendrive?
Is the try ubuntu option working correctly?

Comment: The try ubuntu isn't working. Ad the boot of usb or dvd the problem is starting. I didnt have the problem on 15.04 vivid vervet.

Comment: did you try making the usb again? checked the checksum of downloaded wily?

Comment: On the lts version 14.04 trusty tahr  my dell is working good and  on vivid vervet 15.04 my dell is working goog too. I tried the instalation process many times with 3 diffrent usb and 3 diffrent dvds .I tried to install ubuntu on my friend computer and it was working correctly. I don't no what cause this problem. My drivers are working correctly beacause on windows 10 and 7, and  8,1   I didn't have any problems at all but I want to use ubuntu not windows.

Comment: I have a computer test installed  in bios by dell I Tested  my dell The test didn't show any problems with my computer

Comment: The checksum of willy was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same hardware (xps 8700 with nvidia 745 gtx) and I confirm the problems: graphic looks horrible, words aren't showing correctly, some letters are missing. Moreover, login window (never seen in ubuntu live!) goes blank and then returns to the login screen again in a never ending loop when you try to access.

I can also confirm, with 15.04 all is fine (nouveau).  I'm still investigating the problem. If you create a USB live with persistent capability (see [How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media)) passing 'nomodeset' argument to the kernel when booting (press 'e' on grub and insert 'nomodeset' before 'quiet' argument), you will able to run 15.10 in a low resolution and login window will disappear!

With this configuration, you can try to update ubuntu (apt-get update; apt-get upgrade) or to install nvidia driver since live session uses noveau as default. These systems have failed on my Dell so I think it is a bug related to the new kernel 4.2 (see also this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300068). 
Since live usb with persistency can't update the kernel, in the next week I will try to install Ubuntu on a removable device to try to find out the actual problem. Another way is to update 15.10 iso with a new kernel. Wait and see.

**Update**: a fresh install with 4.2.0-19-generic works fine using nvidia driver 352.63. As stated above, pass *nomodeset* argument to the kernel, update and upgrade ubuntu, and then enable the proprietary nvidia driver.

Comment: I think this should be filed as a bug upstream.